# R AND Operator To New Column

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to learn R (it's not been easy by a long shot) and I'm used to being able to call the AND operator to check if two conditions are met and then inserting that output into a new column. In R, like everything else, this seems difficult to do. In my issue I'm looking to see if a column labeled "PC" is equal to 1 *AND* a column labeled "MF" is equal to 0. If that case is true I want R to output the result (as a 1) to a new column labeled "WR". If any other value is present in either "PC" or "MF" I want R to output a 0 to "WR".

Some Sample Data:

```
PC  MF
1   1
3   1
2   1
4   1
1   1
9   1
2   1
1   1
5   1
5   1
4   0
6   0
8   0
1   1
7   0
1   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `ifelse()` statement:

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(PC=c(1,2,3,4,1), MF=c(0,1,1,1,0))
```

Create a new column based on the two specified conditions

```
df$WR <- ifelse(df$PC==1 & df$MF == 0, 1, 0)
```

Output

```
> df
  PC MF WR
1  1  0  1
2  2  1  0
3  3  1  0
4  4  1  0
5  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 3):

> column labeled "PC" is equal to 1 AND a column labeled "MF" is equal to 0

```
your_data$WR = as.numeric((your_data$PC == 1) & (your_data$MF == 0))
```

Without the `as.numeric` you would get TRUE/FALSE instead of 0/1.

In future questions, I'd recommend showing some of your attempts; then answers can help correct general misunderstandings instead of just providing code for a single small problem.

Comment: or more horribly abstract `(df$PC==1)* (df$MF==0)`

Answer (score 2):

In `data.table` way:

```
DT <- data.table(PC=c(1,2,3,4,1), MF=c(0,1,1,1,0))
DT[, WR:= as.numeric((PC == 1) & (MF == 0))]
```

Output:

```
> DT
   PC MF WR
1:  1  0  1
2:  2  1  0
3:  3  1  0
4:  4  1  0
5:  1  0  1
```